# Rescale an image for printing

Tags: java, printing, scale, rescale

I need to rescale an image for printing, but I only have two different results:

- The image is bigger than the page.
- The image is cutted and I see only a small percent of the image on the page.

I put two images to see it better. The first one is the result that I have now:

[image]

And the second one is the image that I have to see on the page, I have to rescale because is bigger than the page:

[image]

It could be a print problem or the method "rescale" does not works? I put my code below:

```
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) 
          {
            if (pageIndex != 0)
              return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 36));
            g2.setPaint(Color.black);
            g2.scale(200, 200);                 
            g2.drawImage(createImage(temperaturePlot), null, 20, 20);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
          }

    public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) 
   {
   int w = panel.getWidth();
   int h = panel.getHeight();
   BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
   panel.paint(g);

   return bi;       
   }
```

All I want is to scale the image and see all the values on the page.

Any help? Thanks!

I change the method with the new commens, but it doesn't work:

```
class MyPrintableGraphic implements Printable 
        {
          public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) 
          {
            if (pageIndex != 0)
              return NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            BufferedImage original = createImage(temperaturePlot);

            original.getScaledInstance(200, 200,BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 36));
            g2.setPaint(Color.black);
            //BufferedImage image = createImage(temperaturePlot); 
            //Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(200,200,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
            g2.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
            /*BufferedImage mbi = resizeImage(createImage(temperaturePlot), 200, 200);
            g2.drawImage(mbi, null, 20, 20);*/
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
          }
        }
```

Here is the new fail result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with that:

```
g2.drawImage(createImage(temperaturePlot).getScaledInstance(500, 300,BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH), 85, 65, null);
```

I think this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i scaled my images with getScaledInstance

```
BufferedImage.getScaledInstance(width,height,BufferedImage.SCALE_TYPE)
```

this should do the job. It returns you a Buffered image, which when printed has the width and the height you wan't

Comment: I do that: g2.drawImage(createImage(temperaturePlot).getScaledInstance(200,200, BufferedImage.SCALE_DEFAULT), 20, 20, null); But I have my page with nothing now

Comment: try this 
BufferedImage image = createImage(temperaturePlot)
BUfferedImage scaled = image.getScaledInstance(width,height,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)
g2.drawImage(scaled),20,20,null);

Comment: i have the feeling that when you do the scale on the g2 variable you ruin it with that.... everything you do with graphics variable stays until you redo it, for example if you rotate, it stays in rotated position till you change it back, maybe it's somewhere there

Comment: I have this error with your new solution: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.awt.image.ToolkitImage cannot be cast to java.awt.image.BufferedImage, my code was: BufferedImage image = createImage(temperaturePlot); 
            BufferedImage scaled = (BufferedImage) image.getScaledInstance(200,200,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
            g2.drawImage(scaled,20,20,null);

Comment: And if I solve it with that, the page is without nothing one more time: BufferedImage image = createImage(temperaturePlot); 
            Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(200,200,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
            g2.drawImage(scaled,20,20,null);

Comment: aaah, i think i know your problem, you are using 2 different toolkits for image operations. check your imports!!!

Comment: what do you mean with check your imports? can you help me?

Comment: i delete the imports that I don't need, but the result is the same, it rescale some information, but I don't see all the information on the page

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to resize an image an show it in a `JFrame`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);

    BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new File("img.jpg"));
    BufferedImage resized = resizeImage(original, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
        @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(resized, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {
    // calculate the scale factor
    double xScale = width / (double) image.getWidth();
    double yScale = height / (double) image.getHeight();
    // create the object that will contain the resized image
    BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    // resize the image
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) resizedImage.getGraphics();
    g.scale(xScale, yScale);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    // return the resized image
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Here's the result where I set the frame size to 400x400:

[image: Resized image - 400x400]

And here's the 600x400 frame:

[image: Resized image - 600x400]

As you can see, the image fits according to the size of the frame.

Comment: it does not work, I use this two lines of code and it gives me the same result: the page without any image: BufferedImage mbi = resizeImage(createImage(temperaturePlot), 200, 200); g2.drawImage(mbi, null, 20, 20);

Comment: Just edited my answer to show you how to use the method `resizeImage()` in order to set the resized image in a `JPanel`.

Comment: it doesn't work, now I can see the 60% of the image on my page, but not all content, any solution?

Comment: Really? have you used the code I posted without any change?

Comment: I have to change it, because I need to print it, not to put it on a frame, why?

Comment: The method I posted works, how show the images I added to the answer. Now, I think the problem is in the `print()` method, how you use it or how you use the resized image.

Comment: If you use my `resizeImage` method, don't set the `g2.scale(200, 200);` in your `print()` method. That's because you re-scale the image. Could be the cause for which you can see only the 60% of the image in your page.

Comment: I edit my question and you can see my method with your changes, any help? thanks!

Comment: In your `print()` method try with: `if (pageIndex != 0) return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
BufferedImage original = createImage(temperaturePlot);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.drawImage(resizeImage(original, 200, 200), 0, 0, null);
return PAGE_EXISTS;` where `200, 200` is the *width* and the *height* of the image and the `resizeImage()` is my method.

Comment: it doesn't change, the same result, i'm going to put an image of the result and you can see it better, ok?

Comment: Even if you use `g2.drawImage(resizeImage(original, 100, 100), 0, 0, null); `? Remember that `100, 100` are the *width* and the *height* of the image. Feel free to change them as you wish.

Comment: it send me that Exception: java.awt.print.PrinterException: El área de datos transferida a una llamada del sistema es demasiado pequeña. (in english: the area is too small)

Comment: and if I put... 400,400, for example, I have a resized image, but not with all the information of the image

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code for rescaling

```
    BufferedImage imgSource = ImageIO.read(new File("images//Image3.jpg"));
    BufferedImage imgDestination = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = imgDestination.createGraphics();
    AffineTransform affinetransformation = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2, 2);
    g.drawRenderedImage(imgSource, affinetransformation);
    ImageIO.write(imgDestination, "JPG", new File("outImage.jpg"));
```